# in Angular- nvD3 donut chart how to remove radial buttons

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js, angular-nvd3

i am using angular-nvD3 directory for donut chart.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Angular-nvD3 Donut Chart</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.1/nv.d3.min.css"/>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.1/nv.d3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/krispo/angular-nvd3/v1.0.5/dist/angular-nvd3.js"></script>
    <script>var app = angular.module('plunker', ['nvd3']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.options = {
            chart: {
                type: 'pieChart',
                height: 450,
                donut: true,
                x: function(d){return d.key;},
                y: function(d){return d.y;},
                showLabels: true,
                pie: {
                    startAngle: function(d) { return d.startAngle -Math.PI/2 },
                    endAngle: function(d) { return d.endAngle -Math.PI/2 }
                },
                duration: 1,
            }
        };

        $scope.data = [
            {
                key: "One",
                y: 5
            },
            {
                key: "Two",
                y: 2
            },
            {
                key: "Three",
                y: 9
            }
            
        ];
});
   </script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    
    <nvd3 options="options" data="data"></nvd3>
    
  </body>

</html>
```

but i am not getting any idea how to delete above radial buttons (one, two ,three). i don't require them. 
my requirement is [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTfJU.png). i need donut exactly like in the attached screenshot. please help me out from this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add **showLegend: false** to the chart options.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Angular-nvD3 Donut Chart</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.1/nv.d3.min.css"/>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.1/nv.d3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/krispo/angular-nvd3/v1.0.5/dist/angular-nvd3.js"></script>
    <script>var app = angular.module('plunker', ['nvd3']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.options = {
            chart: {
                type: 'pieChart',
                height: 450,
                donut: true,
                x: function(d){return d.key;},
                y: function(d){return d.y;},
                showLabels: true,
                showLegend: false,
                pie: {
                    startAngle: function(d) { return d.startAngle -Math.PI/2 },
                    endAngle: function(d) { return d.endAngle -Math.PI/2 }
                },
                duration: 1,
            }
        };

        $scope.data = [
            {
                key: "One",
                y: 5
            },
            {
                key: "Two",
                y: 2
            },
            {
                key: "Three",
                y: 9
            }
            
        ];
});
   </script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    
    <nvd3 options="options" data="data"></nvd3>
    
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add line in return chart object.

```
showLegend: false
```